Need help refuting a claim in greek and arabic
I would like your help in refuting a Christian claim as this has been bugging me for a while now
Is the epsilon truly more fitting of the first letter of the word "Allah" (as pronounced in Arabic) when when translated to greek from arabic or would it be an intermediate . Also wouldn't starting with epsilon render the pronunciation of the rest of the word incorrect as in Arabic the second alpha isn't really 'a' it's more of an o and the L's are pronounced differently and the xhi at the end would become silent.
I would be grateful if you could respond to this as both Christians and Muslims use this word to refer to God.
https://christianforums.net/threads/666-is-allah.102890/

"Fitting" according to what metric? The only thing in Greek which denotes anything remotely resembling the sound of alif is the smooth breathing (which is not a letter at all), and it doesn't really.
This sounds like one of those desperate theological arguments which will grab any unrelated bit of knowledge from any other field of study to try and argue something which is not susceptible to rational argument.

Answered here.

To the best of my knowledge, Epsilon makes a sound similar to the beginning of the word, "eh". However, both the alif in the beginning of Allah and the fathah over the lam makes a sound between a breathy aa and the beginning sound of 'awe'. In my opinion, the best letter fitting here is omega, so Allah would be written, "Ωλλω".
Akthough, it is true in many cases that the alif and fathah makes a sound like epsilon, but due to an exception made in the rule of Laam, is becomes heavy like  omega.

This is a convincing answer , i don't know why people are downvoting you
